# Assiging indexed values to a structure field

Tags: matlab

I would like a field of my indexed structure to take on a value similarly indexed in a different vector:

```
struc(1:3).value=1:3
```

However, this gives the error `"Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 2 results."`

Enclosing either the left- or the right-hand side of the assignment line in square brackets does not help. And I think `deal` is not suitable, as it just distributes the same value rather than assigning one-to-one values across the vector.

How can I achieve this variable assignment, other than by using a for loop? Using Matlab 2016a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have created `struc` just do:

```
c = num2cell(1:3);
[struc(1:3).value] = c{:};
```

Or create the desired struct in one line:

```
struc = cell2struct(num2cell(1:3), {'value'});
```